# Servlet : doGet and doPost

Tags: java, servlets, portlet, vaadin

I have 2 parameters, `User` and `Pass`. I want to send them to a servlet.

If I use the doGet method of the servlet it would look like this :

```
"link?User="+TextFieldValue+"&pass"textFieldValue

user= UserName.getValue();
pass= password.getValue();

Resource newPictureResource = new ExternalResource("http://localhost:8888/PieChart?UserName="+name+"&Password="+pass);
Success.setSource(newPictureResource);
editContent.addComponent(Success);
```

send them to servlet :

```
    String UserName = request.getParameter("UserName");
    String Password = request.getParameter("Password");
```

It works (tested)

If the `Username` + `pass` are right then he get a "success" picture posted on the screen.

But nobody passes the parameters via URL.

My question: How do I send the parameters using `doPost` method of the servlet ?

info : im working with eclipse on a liferay portal with a Vaadin portlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *send* parameters in `doPost(..)`. You *receive* them there. HTTP has many methods, two of which are GET and POST. It is up to the client-side to choose which method to use. POST is most often used with html forms - `<form method="POST"`.

Vaadin should be able to send POST requests as well - see [this thread](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/713304)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Vaadin interacts, but typically portlet requests are handled differently. Looking though [The Book of Vaadin - Portal Integration](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.portal.html) sheds some insights on configuration and action processing.

If you're looking for a way to handle both request types without reusing logic, simply choose your method of submission by either post or get from your application interface:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Enter logic here
}
```